# Deep Packet Inspection in C#

Tags: c#, networking, encryption, sniffing

Apart from sniffing packets I presume, how can deep packet inspection be done with C#?

Deep packet inspecting in order to find spoofed IPs or proxies and network security.

I cannot find any articles or related websites to this topic for c# so anything relevant is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start here: Pcap.Net is a .NET wrapper for WinPcap written in C++/CLI and C#. http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/

WinPcap is the industry-standard tool for link-layer network access in Windows environments: it allows applications to capture and transmit network packets bypassing the protocol stack, and has additional useful features, including kernel-level packet filtering, a network statistics engine and support for remote packet capture.

Comment: Please include at least a description of the method in your answer; links in itself are not considered an answer.

Comment: Very Interesting, it is packet sniffing sure but what methods can I use to analyze ip headers and find anything suspicious?

Comment: You could read more about the software WireShark. It is based on the WinPCap API.

Comment: Thanks for adding the description and since this is undoubiously the answer, +1 of course :)